# Is it possible automatically switch VPN depending on the destination site?

Tags: vpn

I'm in Australia and sometimes it's good to use VPNs to access content in USA and UK.
However having to switch VPNs to do this and then switch off again to access local content is annoying.

Does anyone know if it is possible to setup multiple VPNs and then automatically switch between them or not use them depending on the web site you are accessing?

EG:

```
set of IP addresses           -> VPN1
different set of IP addresses -> VPN2
everything else               -> no VPN
```